# Неправильная позиция объекта при конвертации из .dxf в .obj

Tags: python, 3d, obj, dxf

Требуется сконвертировать файл формата .dxf в .obj
Эти модели в дальнейшем загружаются в threejs
С помощью библиотеки ezdxf был написан следующий код:

```py
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.addons import meshex
from ezdxf.render import MeshBuilder

ms = MeshBuilder()
filename = "Polosti"
doc = ezdxf.readfile(f"{filename}.dxf")

msp = doc.modelspace()

for entity in msp:
    if entity.dxftype() == "POLYLINE":
        mesh = MeshBuilder.from_polyface(entity)
        ms.vertices += mesh.vertices
        ms.faces += mesh.faces
    elif entity.dxftype() == "3DFACE":
        ms.add_face([entity.dxf.vtx0, entity.dxf.vtx1, entity.dxf.vtx2, entity.dxf.vtx3])
    elif entity.dxftype() == "LINE":
        ms.add_vertices([entity.dxf.start, entity.dxf.end])

with open(f"{filename}.obj", "wt") as fp:
    fp.write(meshex.obj_dumps(ms))
```

Он вполне работает, конвертация проходит успешно
Однако, некоторые модели вместо нулевых координат находятся где-то очень далеко
Например, [эта](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cxJlVRaFYoTEtriwAKPitXJN53adjXWU/view?usp=sharing)
Как "нормализовать" эти координаты?